MSFT PowerAutomate - Dynamic dropdown on Custom connector doesn't work
I have created a custom connector from scratch & used a dropdown that is configured as a operation. That operation doesn't apply at that parameter in the test window. How do I check it out them? I have checked them at Swagger Editor. It shows as below

name: teamId
in: query
required: true
type: string
description: Team ID
x-ms-dynamic-values:
operationId: GetProductList
value-path: teamId
value-title: teamId
parameters:
Accept:
parameter: teamId

I have tested them at Test window. Parameter doesn't look as dropdown in Test window. How do I test it then?
